# accessing the dom element of a sibiling component in another sibiling component angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

consider the case of two sibling components in an angular 2 component. I want to get the dom element in a sibiling component and make that available in the next sibling component. How can I achieve this?

For sibling component interation we can make use of a service. So should I pass that element via a service. Is this the proper way to acheive it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May i ask what you're trying to do?  it seems weird that a component should directly care about its sibling - that sort of interaction should, at best, be between parent and child, in most cases

Comment: I want to get the height of an element in the first sibling component and use that value in the second sibling component

Comment: @mechev you can use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) but it is considered as security risk.

Comment: As you hinted at, how about using a service to do that interaction?  The first sibling can set the height value as some sort of data property in the service, and the other sibling can then retrieve that value and use as needed

Comment: [This tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/responsive-equal-height-with-angular-directive) seems to have some code to do what you want.